# Responsive menu will open but not close using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

my respoonsive menu will open using JQuery but is not selectable to close again. Any ideas?

JQUERY CODE

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#menu-trigger").click(function() {
        jQuery("#menu").slideToggle(400, function() {
            jQuery(this).togglediv("#menu-expanded").css('display', '');
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```css
#menu-trigger {display:none;}
@media screen and (max-width:480px)
{
    #menu-trigger {display:block;}
    #menu {display:none;}
    #menu-expanded {display:block;}
}
```

HTML:
The HTML code is using div id="menu-trigger" and div id="menu"

Comment: I don't think `togglediv()` is a jQuery method...?

Comment: If you remove the entire line containing `togglediv()` then it should work ok: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Comment: The toggleDiv() function cause an error, so the code doesn't work then. But before it, the code work correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for comments. I changed my Java Script. It was working, I minified it and now now. This is my new code. Is this correct?jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function() {
        jQuery(".menu").slideToggle(100, function() {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("menu-expanded").css("display", "");
        });
    });
});